# While submitting a form IE8 won't add attributes to the request other than those from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer-8, submit

All other browsers (including IE9, exluding ancient ones) send correct requests for the following form:

```
<form class="form-submitter form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Uploader" id="Uploader" action="MainServlet?module=general&action=add&Name=test">
<input class="input-file" name="testFormName" id="UploaderInput" type="file">
</form>
```

That is:

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/MainServlet?module=general&action=add&Name=test&testFormName=%5Bobject+File%5D
```

while in IE8 all I get is:

```
http://localhost:8080/Project/MainServlet?toSessionFormName=test.png
```

I'm using jQuery's submit, that is:

```
$("#Uploader").submit()
```

I'd love to get any suggestions, or tips which could lead to me to solution. Did anyone has this problem already with IE8?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hidden inputs :

```
<form class="form-submitter form-horizontal"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Uploader" id="Uploader"
    action="MainServlet">
    <input type=hidden name=module value="general">
    <input type=hidden name=action value="add">
    <input type=hidden name=Name value="test">
    <input class="input-file" name="testFormName" id="UploaderInput" type="file">
</form>
```

That's the right solution. You'll even avoid encoding problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code this way:

```
<form class="form-submitter form-horizontal"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      name="Uploader" id="Uploader"
      action="MainServlet" method="get">
    <input class="input-file" name="testFormName" id="UploaderInput" type="file">
    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="general" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="test" />
</form>
```

It is better to implicitly send the parameters through GET rather than in URL.